# Discord.py send friend requests

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Wondering how to send friend-requests with id.txt as infile.
My code looks like this but does not work

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    with open("id.txt") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            id = int(line)
            user = await client.get_user_info(id)
                try:
                    time.sleep(.305)
                    await user.send.friend_request
                except (discord.Forbidden, discord.HTTPException):
                    continue
```

Comment: Are you _calling_ `user.send.friend_request` and should you be calling it?

Comment: bot accounts cannot accept or send friend requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct coroutine is [`User.send_friend_request`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.User.send_friend_request), which you have to call.

```
from asyncio import sleep

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    with open("id.txt") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            id = int(line)
            user = await client.get_user_info(id)
            try:
                await sleep(.305)
                await user.send_friend_request()
            except (discord.Forbidden, discord.HTTPException):
                continue
```

You should also use `asyncio.sleep` to avoid unnecessary blocking.